# flutter 2.10.0 build failed with win32-2.3.11/lib/src/structs.g.dart:666:31: Error: Member not found

Tags: flutter, dart

flutter 2.10.0 build failed
and the log like this:

```
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/50/z6jgw_3s1cvcqkyx0wc4llnc0000gn/T/flutter_tools.B4L9K8/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirM0C4eg/temporary_xcresult_bundle

    ../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.3.11/lib/src/structs.g.dart:666:31: Error: Member not found: 'UnicodeChar'.
      int get UnicodeChar => Char.UnicodeChar;
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.3.11/lib/src/structs.g.dart:667:38: Error: Setter not found: 'UnicodeChar'.
      set UnicodeChar(int value) => Char.UnicodeChar = value;
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.3.11/lib/src/structs.g.dart:669:29: Error: Member not found: 'AsciiChar'.
      int get AsciiChar => Char.AsciiChar;
                                ^^^^^^^^^
    ../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.3.11/lib/src/structs.g.dart:670:36: Error: Setter not found: 'AsciiChar'.
      set AsciiChar(int value) => Char.AsciiChar = value;
                                       ^^^^^^^^^
    Failed to package /Users/kangkang/Documents/hezhot.
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in parallel

    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/50/z6jgw_3s1cvcqkyx0wc4llnc0000gn/T/flutter_tools.B4L9K8/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirM0C4eg/temporary_xcresult_bundle


Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11.
```

why dose it happended in flutter 2.10.0 dart 2.16.0

and I found maybe relevant to this issue :

[enter link description here](https://github.com/timsneath/win32_runner/issues/1)

what can I actually do?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72233476/flutter-error-member-not-found-unicodechar