# Flutter Error: Member not found: 'UnicodeChar'

Tags: flutter, dart

After upgrading to flutter 3.0.0.
i am getting this error:

```
Error: Member not found: 'UnicodeChar'.
  int get UnicodeChar => Char.UnicodeChar;

Error: Setter not found: 'UnicodeChar'.
  set UnicodeChar(int value) => Char.UnicodeChar = value;

Error: Member not found: 'AsciiChar'.
  int get AsciiChar => Char.AsciiChar;

Error: Setter not found: 'AsciiChar'.
  set AsciiChar(int value) => Char.AsciiChar = value;
```

here is the image:
[image]

Comment: It looks like the error is in the [win32](https://pub.dev/packages/win32) package. Do you still get this error if you update the version of `win32` in your `pubspec.yaml` file?

Comment: https://github.com/timsneath/win32/issues/424

Answer (score 89, accepted):

In my case, it was one of the transitive dependencies that was outdated.

Upgrading dependencies resolved the issue for me.

##### From the Terminal (inside the project's folder):

`flutter pub upgrade`

##### From Visual Studio Code

1. Open **Command Palette...** (<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on MacOS)
2. Type `Flutter: Upgrade Packages`

##### From Android Studio

1. Open **Search Everywhere** (<kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> on MacOS)
2. Type `Flutter Pub Upgrade`

Comment: I need to run `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions` to resolve major version dependencies constraints

Answer (score 31):

To solve the error do the following

1. upgrade all the third party packages
2. flutter clean
3. delete pubspec.lock file
4. flutter pub get

You can learn more from the link below
https://youtu.be/lxeB5ZZyJXM

Answer (score -7):

if it happens to you during `flutterfire configure` command put it into your terminal to fix it:

```
dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
```