# failed iOS build from Codemagic

Tags: flutter, dart, codemagic

Im trying to build a iOS in codemagic.io and after try it, it return the error below

```
== Building for iOS ==

> flutter build ios --debug --no-codesign
Running "flutter pub get" in clone...                            1,350ms
Warning: Building for device with codesigning disabled. You will have to manually codesign before deploying to device.
Building com.testing.correiosNovo for device (ios)...
Upgrading Info.plist
Running pod install...                                           1,296ms
Running Xcode build...                                          
Xcode build done.                                           14.6s


Build failed :|
Failed to build for iOS
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2022-09-23 23:19:22.708 xcodebuild[1114:7432] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    2022-09-23 23:19:22.709 xcodebuild[1114:7432] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcodes output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        

    ../programs/flutter_3_3_2/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.3.6/lib/src/structs.g.dart:661:31: Error: Member not found: 'UnicodeChar'.
      int get UnicodeChar => Char.UnicodeChar;
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../programs/flutter_3_3_2/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.3.6/lib/src/structs.g.dart:662:38: Error: Setter not found: 'UnicodeChar'.
      set UnicodeChar(int value) => Char.UnicodeChar = value;
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../programs/flutter_3_3_2/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.3.6/lib/src/structs.g.dart:664:29: Error: Member not found: 'AsciiChar'.
      int get AsciiChar => Char.AsciiChar;
                                ^^^^^^^^^
    ../programs/flutter_3_3_2/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.3.6/lib/src/structs.g.dart:665:36: Error: Setter not found: 'AsciiChar'.
      set AsciiChar(int value) => Char.AsciiChar = value;
                                       ^^^^^^^^^
    Failed to package /Users/builder/clone.
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order

    Result bundle written to path:
        


Encountered error while building for device.
```

I do the process to build iOS in my computer

> flutter build ios

after it, upload to Codemagic and start the process to generate app to iOS, but it return the error above, I try to find any solution to it, and can't, it returns the error every time I build it.

Comment: See this question: [flutter-error-member-not-found-unicodechar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72233476/flutter-error-member-not-found-unicodechar)

Comment: It is strange that in this error log it says win32, is this not windows? Is your machine on codemagic windows or mac?

Comment: @Chance its macOS M1 Standard VM - Apple M1 / 3.2GHz Quad Core / 8GB

Answer (score 1):

I think you use old Flutter version on your local machine and latest `3.3.2` when you building on Codemagic and some packages are not compatible with this version.

At Codemagic you can specify any Flutter version in build settings to reproduce your local environment and this should fix the error.

Alternative solution will be to upgrade your packages. Check this thread for more information https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/103565